# Cambiar el color del status bar de android

Tags: android, color

Quiero cambiar el color del status bar de mi app en android. Tengo este código pero no funciona:

```
Log.e("Resultado", Build.VERSION.SDK_INT +">="+ Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window statusBar = getWindow();
    statusBar.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        statusBar.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(colorElegido, getTheme()));

    }
    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        statusBar.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(colorElegido));
    }
}
```

El dispositivo en el que lo estoy probando tiene `android 5`.

La app se me cierra y no me muestra cual es el error.

El id del color es: `-15392107`

Utilizo este código para obtener el id del color:

```
private Integer getParseColor(String color) {
    if (color != null && !color.equals("")  && !color.equals("null")) {
        return Color.parseColor(color);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Si cambio la variable `colorElegido` por esto por ejemplo: `R.color.white` si funciona.

La única excepción que encuentro es esta:

```
06-22 13:09:27.639 3162-3177/? W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.huawei.lcagent.client.LogCollectManager.getUserType()' on a null object reference
06-22 13:09:27.639 3162-3177/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.util.ReportTools.getUserType(ReportTools.java:86)
06-22 13:09:27.639 3162-3177/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.util.ReportTools.isBetaUser(ReportTools.java:73)
06-22 13:09:27.639 3162-3177/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.util.ReportTools.report(ReportTools.java:58)
06-22 13:09:27.639 3162-3177/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.util.HwUserBehaviourRecord.appExitRecord(HwUserBehaviourRecord.java:65)
06-22 13:09:27.640 3162-3177/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$UiHandler.handleMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:1572)
06-22 13:09:27.640 3162-3177/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-22 13:09:27.640 3162-3177/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
06-22 13:09:27.640 3162-3177/? W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
06-22 13:09:27.640 3162-3177/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

¿Puede ser el error porque la variable `colorElegido` sea negativa?

Despues de esta linea tengo puesto dos logs pero no muestran, asi que me imagino que sera ahi:

```
statusBar.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(colorElegido, getTheme()));
```

Comment: Por qué no funciona?  el resultado no es el esperado? sale un error? has probado en un emulador o en el dispositivo fisico? Por favor añade toda la informacion relevante para su resolucion

Comment: Ya lo he editado @lois6b

Comment: de Window statusBar = getWindow(); bueno que es el mismo que tu variable window

Comment: Pero el error que te muestra es que hay una nulalidad y el getParseColor() diría que lo controla, estas seguro que es en esta línea el error?

Comment: No, no lo estoy, pero es la unica excepcion que encuentro no hay nada mas. He añadido mas explicación a mi pregunta. Si cambio la variable colorElegido por esto por ejemplo: R.color.white si funciona.  @Webserveis

Comment: prueba que devuelve int y no Intenger y si puede que lo de negativo sea el causante.

Comment: El color en hexadeciamla es: `#152295` y al aplicarle `Color.parseColor` devuelve: `-15392107` @Webserveis

Comment: Si ahora estoy haciendo pruebas y si que el negativo no afecta en absoluto, mm ni idea de que puede ser el error en el log de error no te sale el caused: ¿?

Comment: Me sale esto tambien, pero no en rojo: `W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0xff152295 (t=20 e=8853) (error -2147483647)` @Webserveis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo es posible cambiar el color de la `status-bar` a partir de la versión Android L para delante.

Yo uso lo siguiente:

```
int myColor = Color.parseColor("#3F51B5");

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(myColor);
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(myColor);
}
```

Comment: Encontre el error, tu solución me funciono, yo tenia puesto esto: `statusBar.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(colorElegido, getTheme()));`